# Set location that listens to / and any subpaths

Tags: nginx, docker

I'm tinkering with Docker and NGINX and I have an angular app that is currently responding to http://localhost. When you click a link in my app, it updates the url in your browser to http://localhost/home. If you refresh the page though you get the standard nginx 404 page.

How can I modify my nginx.conf file so that http://localhost and http://localhost/home will display my angular app instead of a 404?

nginx.conf

```
events {}

http {

  index index.html;

  server {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    location / {
       #proxy_pass /
    }
  }
}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx
COPY ./dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: Please show the complete configuration.

Comment: That is the complete configuration.

Comment: The virtual server block is missing `listen` directive, and possibly `server_name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems all I needed was the `try_files` line.

```
events {}

http {

  index index.html;

  server {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
  }
}
```